# Making standalone grizzly2 JAX-RS accept an encoded URL in the URL?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, grizzly

I am experimenting with enclosing a possibly leaky library in its own standalone JVM and invoke it using REST.  I have a Java EE 7 web app which does this, but I would like a stand alone version.  To do this I have created a small Maven project using

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes \
 -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-grizzly2 -DarchetypeVersion=2.27
```

This gave me a small project with this Main.

```
public class Main {
    // Base URI the Grizzly HTTP server will listen on
    public static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/verapdf/";

    /**
     * Starts Grizzly HTTP server exposing JAX-RS resources defined in this application.
     * @return Grizzly HTTP server.
     */
    public static HttpServer startServer() {
        // create a resource config that scans for JAX-RS resources and providers
        // in dk.kb.dpa.verapdf package
        final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("dk.kb.dpa.verapdf");

        // create and start a new instance of grizzly http server
        // exposing the Jersey application at BASE_URI
        return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);
    }

    /**
     * Main method.
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final HttpServer server = startServer();
        System.out.println(String.format("Jersey app started with WADL available at "
                + "%sapplication.wadl\nHit enter to stop it...", BASE_URI));
        System.in.read();
        server.stop();
    }
}
```

I have added my own small resource looking like:

```
.
.
.
@Path("validate")
public class JAXRSValidator {

    @GET
    @Path("{url}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public String validate(@PathParam("url") String url) throws Exception 
.
.
.
```

This works in so far that I can invoke `http://localhost:8080/verapdf/validate/123` and hit a breakpoint inside the method with `url` set to `123`.   I, however, would like to have a real URL here (which will be absolute and include both slashes and hashmarks) and this gives an error 500.  As the method is not invoked I suspect that the web container and/or JAX-RS dislikes my encoded URL in the correct location, much as Tomcat appears to do.

How do I solve this?  Another approach is fine, as long as I end up with a stand-alone binary providing a REST service.

Comment: I believe there is something wrong with ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH. Please read, maybe it help: http://buchireddy.github.io/glassfish/rest/grizzly/apache/2014/06/06/handling-slash-encoded-urls-in-glassfish.html

Comment: Decided to move it to a query parameter instead of having to workaround every container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned in comment there is problem with slash decoding. You can enable decoding slash explicitly:

```
public static HttpServer startServer() {
    final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("dk.kb.dpa.verapdf");
    HttpServer httpServer = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);
    httpServer.getHttpHandler().setAllowEncodedSlash(true);
    return httpServer;
}
```

Without `allowEncodedSlash` HTTP server throws and catch internally exception during decoding encoded slash. By default slash decoding is forbidden:

```
java.io.CharConversionException: Encoded slashes are not allowed
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:251)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.URLDecoder.decodeAscii(URLDecoder.java:159)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.HttpRequestURIDecoder.decode(HttpRequestURIDecoder.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.RequestURIRef.getDecodedRequestURIBC(RequestURIRef.java:138)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.RequestURIRef.getDecodedRequestURIBC(RequestURIRef.java:124)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandlerChain.doHandle(HttpHandlerChain.java:203)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.SameThreadIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(SameThreadIOStrategy.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeyEvents(SelectorRunner.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeys(SelectorRunner.java:396)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.doSelect(SelectorRunner.java:358)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.run(SelectorRunner.java:281)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.io.CharConversionException: Encoded slashes are not allowed
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:251)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.URLDecoder.decodeAscii(URLDecoder.java:159)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.HttpRequestURIDecoder.decode(HttpRequestURIDecoder.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.RequestURIRef.getDecodedRequestURIBC(RequestURIRef.java:138)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.RequestURIRef.getDecodedRequestURIBC(RequestURIRef.java:124)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandlerChain.doHandle(HttpHandlerChain.java:203)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.SameThreadIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(SameThreadIOStrategy.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeyEvents(SelectorRunner.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeys(SelectorRunner.java:396)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.doSelect(SelectorRunner.java:358)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.run(SelectorRunner.java:281)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```